# How to get properties from a list of objects binded to a CarouselView in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

I have a list of objects binded to a CarouselView. Inside the CarouselView is a simple DataTemplate containing some labels that are supposed to be binded to the properties of the object. However the properties are not recognized.

I am using CommunityToolKit.Mvvm for a simple MVVM solution.

The error I am getting is in the View on Line 16:

```
Error   XFC0045 Binding: Property "Name" not found on "MauiTest.ViewModels.MainViewModel".
```

Line that the error originates from:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
```

View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiTest.MainPage"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MauiTest.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="vm:MainViewModel">

  <StackLayout>
    
    <CarouselView BindingContext="{Binding Models}" >
      
      <CarouselView.ItemTemplate> 
        <DataTemplate>
          <ContentView>
            <StackLayout >
              <Label Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
              <Label Text="{Binding Path=Description}" />
            </StackLayout>
          </ContentView>
        </DataTemplate>
      </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
      
    </CarouselView>
    
  </StackLayout>
  
</ContentPage>
```

Model:

```
public partial class TestModel : ObservableObject
{
  [ObservableProperty]
  private string m_name;

  [ObservableProperty]
  private string m_description;

  public TestModel(string name, string description) 
  {
    Name = name;
    Description = description;
  }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
  [ObservableProperty]
  private List<TestModel> m_models;
  public MainViewModel() 
  {
    Models = new List<TestModel>
    {
      new TestModel("name1", "test1"),                                   
      new TestModel("name2", "test2")
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says that it is trying to find property `Name` on `MainViewModel`.

The reason it is looking there (instead of in `TestModel`), is this xaml:

```xml
x:DataType="vm:MainViewModel"
```

As soon as you add **any** `x:DataType` to a xaml file, you have to add the correct `x:DataType`, anywhere it changes.

There are two different ways you can fix:

- Either: remove all `x:Datatype`s from the xaml file.
- Or: add the missing `x:Datatype`:

```xml
<ContentView x:DataType="PutCorrectNamespaceHere.TestModel">
```

NOTE: Not tested. I'm not sure that is the correct line to put the missing `x:DataType`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following MVVM way:

In xaml, you could set the **ItemsSource** property to **Models**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="GetProperties75380426.MainPage"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:GetProperties75380426.ViewModel"
         >


<StackLayout>
    <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Models}"  >     
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate> 
            <DataTemplate>
            <ContentView>
                <StackLayout >
                    <Label Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Path=Description}" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ContentView>
            </DataTemplate>
         </CarouselView.ItemTemplate> 
     </CarouselView>
</StackLayout>
```

In .cs file, set the BindingContext of the page, that is the MainViewModel

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.BindingContext = new MainViewModel();
}
```

For more info, you could refer to [Populate a CarouselView with data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/carouselview/populate-data?view=net-maui-7.0).

Hope it works for you.

Comment: I have the BindingContext set in the Back-end code just like that, but the property is still not being recognized as the object's

Comment: have you set the ItemSource property of CarouselView? Seems that you set the BindingContext to Models

Comment: I have updated my answer with more code, you could have a try.@notCamelCase